# Alert box containing List of array list values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a text box for entering multiple Student_names from database separated by ";" along with a Button. When this button clicks, I want to separate each student_name from textbox and wants to check if the entered student names are valid/is it exists in the database table.Now my need is, If any one of them is not exists I wants to generate an alert box saying "Student with "Student name" doesn't exist". If more than one names are not valid, then wants to display, "Student with studentname1,2,.. are not exists" How is this possible??

```
 String PageRefs =TextBox1.Text;

    if (PageRefs.Contains(";"))
    {
        String[] PageRefArray = PageRefs.Split(';');

        for (int f = 0; f < PageRefArray.Length; f++)
        {
           String name = PageRefArray[f];
  //Comparing the values from table to check name  exists in table.here for example the default name is set to "Niya"
            if (name  != "niya")
             {
                 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('studentID '"+name +'" doesnt exists')", true);
                return;
         }
        }
```

How can I display list of student name that doesn't exists on alert box ?

Comment: You need to replace `if (name  != "niya")` with a call to a database. -1 As it is this question is lacking a lot of detail and too open ended. Without the Database Type, Schema we cannot answer this question in its current form

Comment: My problem is not with the values on database. I just want to know how can i display list of values on alert box. I hope, for that this explanation is enough. Thats why not giving important in writing query . @ Jeremy Thompson

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You will need to concatenate the multiple values into a (comma) delimited string. Just lookup the string `Join` method. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure what exactly the problem is but from what I gather it's generating the error listing the invalid users, so how about something like:

```
// get the users from the textbox 
string[] users = input.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// check if the user doesn't exist in the database and add him to a list of invalid users
List<string> invalidUsers = users.Where(user => !UserExists(user)).ToList();

// generate an error message
string errorMessage = string.Format("Students with the usernames: {0} don't exists",
                                    string.Join(", ", invalidUsers));
```

This will of course produce:

> Students with the usernames: test, 123123 don't exists

Comment: showing an error "UserExists doesnt exists ". please help @Dimitar Dimitrov

Comment: @ARATHY Yes, that's a boolean method that checks the database for each user, you can write your own, not sure on your database details, it's there to give you an idea.